# How can I display php file to the screen

Tags: php, file

How can I display php file to the screen from this php file?
So php script should display own code.
Conditions - file and input statements are forbidden!!!

Comment: Sorry, forgot about conditions - file and input statements are forbidden!!!

Comment: The conditions don't make sense, please use actual PHP expressions so we will know what you mean.

Comment: It is forbidden to use function for reading file (fopen, file_get_contents etc)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('you_php_file.php');
?>
```

or simply

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents(__FILE__);
?>
```

Read more about `file_get_contents` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and about `__FILE__` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: I forgot about too conditions in description

Answer (score 1):

use `highlight_file` so that you can get the source code in nice color formatting.

```
highlight_file($file_name);
```

Comment: I forgot about too conditions in description

Answer (score 0):

If the PHP is loading, you could simply echo the code, though you have to escape the (double) quotes ofcourse:

Echo '$testvar1 = \'butterfly\'; 
$testvar2 = \'elephant\';';

Or if indeed you want to display all the code, donCallisto's method is better ;-)

Comment: I forgot about too conditions in description

Answer (score 0):

To have a php file display its own code you could do it like so:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents(__FILE__);
?>
```

to get another file's contents

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("other_file.php");
?>
```

Comment: I forgot about too conditions in description

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($file));
```

(otherwise, if you use `echo file_get_contents($file);`
you have to click **View>Source** on page, to see the content, as they are put in `<>`)